# Replacing TightVNC with alternate client (CONNECT parameter)

Tags: proxy, openvz, vnc

I am in the process of reverse engineering an existing system in an attempt to replace their existing TightVNC applet with something else (hopefully [NoVNC](http://kanaka.github.com/noVNC/) if at all possible).

So far, here is what I know...

- Debian server
- OpenVZ linux VMs inside of it that runs apps on-demand for users
- Users connect to OpenVZ VMs via generated parameters (TightVNC uses these)

I've been able to connect using the TightVNC Java jar using connection params like this:

```
java -jar VncViewer-20070502-01.jar
    HOST myhost.com
    PORT 443
    ENCPASSWORD 234f92c02c3b128e
    CONNECT vncsession:0c5a727371e5d10e3147566e389b28c3
    DisableSSL No
```

I believe that this connects to the server using an HTTPS proxy and then reroutes to a specific OpenVZ session, but I cannot be 100% sure of the process. I am unable to ping `vncsession` from the Debian server or the OpenVZ instances, so I'm not exactly sure what it even is.

Some of these parameters are covered in the [TightVNC README](http://www.tightvnc.com/doc/java/README.txt) - but not all of them.

Right now I am facing two problems...

1. `ENCPASSWORD` is a non-standard parameter as far as I can tell. Through decompiling the TightVNC jar I can tell that this is simply decrypted back into plain text, so I have no idea what the purpose of this is... The passwords are randomly generated in the first place.
2. I have no idea how `CONNECT` works, or how to use it on any VNC client besides TightVNC. I believe it has something to do with the proxy routing.

Can anyone help me understand these parameters, especially the `CONNECT` parameter? Any additional help with using another VNC client in place of TightVNC would be appreciated as well. Thank you!

Comment: After some additional digging into the TightVNC source I'm seeing that this may have been modified and recompiled... making this entire VNC viewer setup non-standard. This could explain my difficulty in figuring out how it works.